# Running Watch Simulator and iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos-2

When I'm running the Apple Watch simulator from Xcode, both the iOS simulator and the Watch Simulator launch but the iOS app doesn't start up.  Is that by design or am I doing something wrong?  I can launch either in the simulators and they communicate as expected but if both would launch at the same time that would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode doesn't have an option to automatically run both apps for you.

The existing approach is historically by design, but there are other reasons for it too.  For example:

- It's faster, and uses less resources to not unnecessarily (build, install and) launch the host app.
- You may want to test that the watch app works as expected when it *can't* communicate with its paired device *or* app.

Within Xcode, you tell it to run a particular app, whether it be the iOS app or the watchOS app. That's the (only) app that launches.

The best you can do (within Xcode) is to first run the iOS app, then run the watchOS app. Both will be running, and you can then debug either one from within Xcode.

Of course, you could always [submit a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to add an option to launch both apps.